# Link View Layer to a specific camera (in Blender)

Tags: camera, viewlayers

is it possible to link a View Layer to a specific camera?
So I have different Cameras (for different shots) in my scene and also different view layers, that some objects are only visible, in specific shots.
Since I don't have to render each shot individually by hand, I also installed the Ubisoft Shot Manager, but now of course I can no longer use the "Render Single Layer" function...
Is there any way to assign a camera to a specific shot in Blender or in the shot manager?